# After page loads I can't execute Javascript functions that access properties from console

Tags: javascript, debugging, invoke

I have a page that loads a bunch of scripts to prepopulate dropdowns and has scripts within the html onclick events and etc.

After the page loads and I open the page in the script console I can't do anything. everything is null and functions non-existent.

For example there is an onClick function `onclick="Popup('Seattle');"`.

If I try to invoke that from the script console I get Object Expected error like it doesn't even exist. But if I click the button the method fires right up. I can't modify this code so it's important that I get this functions going.

While I'm stepping through the code and have the script paused I have access to everything but as soon as it's finished it's back to nothing at all.

Anyone know what's going on and is there a way to invoke these functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Object expected" sounds like for example the `Popup` function wants to be called like `Popup.call(somedomnode, args...)`. When called from an event handler, `this` is set to the element the handler is called on. If you just try to call it without some object as `this`, it might complain.

Otherwise probably the functions you want to call are not in scope at top-level. You don't really tell us how these functions are defined or how the event handlers get set up, so it's hard to say more where the problem might be.

Comment: You can find a sample copy of the page here http://www.dailynewstube.com/newlist.htm  unfortunately the real site is password protected